# Are there any Route Server for Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, route

Are there any router servers, like zebra, for Windows Server?

Comment: Other than RRAS? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754634%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: Looking for BGP support!

Comment: A BGP router on Windows? I think you might be using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Ah, gotcha

Comment: @evan - just building a listener.... i know already done in linux, but need it for windows...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'd want to use it in production but checkout [VNE](http://wiki.ucis.nl/VNE)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but i found this when looking for something else... Looks like [Windows Server 2012 R2](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/networking/2013/10/11/border-gateway-protocol-bgp-with-windows-server-2012-r2/) has BGP support in it.